# R: GMM Estimators in a dynamic panel

Tags: r, panel-data, autoregressive, generalized-moments, plm

I put up a fixed effects regression using panel data with a time lag of the dependant variable, so somthing like this:

```
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
attach(data)
panel_data <- pdata.frame(data, index = c("country","time"))

model1 <- plm(Y~Y_l1+A+B+C, data = panel_data, model = "within",  effect = "twoway")
```

Where Y_l1 is the time lag of the dependant variable and A,B,C are other explanatory variables. I am using robust st. err. as well

```
robmodel <- coeftest(model1, vcov.=vcovHC(model1, method = c("arellano")))
```

My advisor now told me that as my number of time periods is rather small (its about 15) I should include GMM estimators for dynamic panels. He said it is fairly simple to include them in Stata, I however use R, therefore, I wanted to know if there is a simple way to include them in R as well? Is it possible to do it with one line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic panels are usually dealt with using GMM. Check pgmm in plm. It should be quite straightforward to follow.

https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i02/v27i02.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I am getting: `error  in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute` do you know why that could be?

Comment: What did you run?

Comment: `attach(data)`
`panel_data <- pdata.frame(data, index = c("country","time"))  ` 
`GMMmodel <-  pgmm(A~lag(A_l1)+B,effect="twoways",model="twosteps")`

Comment: See the document for section 5.4 on page 16. You need dynformula to define your lag structure.

Comment: I am kind of a newbie in R or any kind of programming, could you tell me how the code would look like with my example from the initial question?

Comment: Please, do not use `dynformula` as it is deprecated. Also, please use the package's vignette which is an updated version of the cited article.

Comment: So what shall I use instead of 'dynformula' ?

Comment: @Helix123 the current vignette is unfortunately not an "updated version of the cited article", as the latter has a much more thorough explanation.

Comment: @ArOk "dynformula was used to construct a dynamic formula which was the first argument of pgmm. pgmm uses now multi-part formulas." (from http://search.r-project.org/library/plm/html/plm-deprecated.html )

Answer (score 2):

there is a "pgmm" option: estimation of generalized method of moments models for panel data in "plm" package. It should be a corresponding function in R to xtabond2 from Stata (see [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf) and [Author's description](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i02/v27i02.pdf))